# Linear algebra, finding basis for orthogonal complement of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the text, I am new to this.
We have the vector space $$V=P_3(R)$$ under the inner product:
$$\langle f,g\rangle=f(-2)g(-2)+f(-1)g(-1)+f(0)g(0)+f(1)g(1)$$

Let:
$$p(x)=x^3+3x^2+2x$$
and:
$$q(x)=x-1$$

Let the vector space $W$:
$$W=\mathrm {span}(p(x),q(x))$$
Give a basis for the orthogonal complement of $W$, that is $W^\perp$

I already have the correct answer, and made large amount progress of this question, but I cannot figure  out fully how the process is done.
Answer: $$(7x^2+4x-11, 7x^3-16x+9)$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $p(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)$, so the values at $x=-2,-1,0,1$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & -2 & -1 & 0& 1 \\
\hline
p & 0 & 0 & 0&6 \\
q & -3 & -2 & -1&0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Then to find a orthonormal complement $g,h$, we just need to satisfying the inner product with each other being $0$, which shouldn't give too messy calculation.

For example, the following works:$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & -2 & -1 & 0& 1 \\
\hline
g & 0 & -1 & 2 &0 \\
h & -\frac 53 & 2 & 1&0 \\
\end{array}
$$
With other places $0$. Using this, you then can easily find $2$ degree $3$ polynomial that satisfy the condition.

An example way to find it is shown below:

Based on the zeros of $g$, we have:
$$g(x)=g'(x)\,(x-1)(x+2)$$
With $g'(0)=-1$, $\,g'(-1)=\frac 12$, then $g'(x)=-\frac 32x-1$, so:
$$g(x)=-(\frac32x+1)(x-1)(x+2)$$

Now if $h(x)=1-x+h'(x)$, then $h(x)$ is matched except at $x=-2$, so
$$h'(x)=kx(x+1)(x-1)$$
Plugging in $x=-2$, we have $-\frac 53=3-6k$, and $k=\frac 79$, so:
$$h(x)=-(x-1)+\frac 79x(x+1)(x-1)=\frac 19(x-1)(7x^2+7x-9)$$

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand it, how do you get an answer in this case?

Comment: @Logan There's a unique degree at most $n$ polynomial passing through $n+1$ points, see [Polynomial Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). A easy way to find it can be given by [Newton polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial).

Comment: @Logan Updated answer to include examples of how to find the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Writing down what it means for the inner products $\langle p(x),f(x)\rangle,\langle q(x),f(x)\rangle$ to be zero will give you a couple of equations.  Let $f(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$.  The two equations will knock the dimension down by two:  you should get a two-dimensional vector space as your solution.

Comment: hi, yes, I did it this way, but I can't get the correct solution

Comment: I have two equations, let $$f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$      I have first $$a+b+c+d=0$$  Second: $$-3a+4b-7c+13d=0$$

Comment: When I use this two equations in $$a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$  I have no idea how to get the answer.   Can someone help me?

Comment: Four unknowns and two equations.  Choose nice values for $c$ and $d$.  Like $c=1,d=0$.  Then  we have $a+b=-1$ and $-3a+4b=7$.  We get $b=4/7, a=-11/7$.    So we have $-11+4x+7x^2$ as one solution.  Now let $c=0,d=1$.  We get $a+b=-1, -3a+4b=-13$.  Solving, we get $b=-16/7,a=-23/7$.  Thus we get $9-16x+7x^3$.  These two polynomials form a basis for  $W^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!   I got it!!

Comment: Sure thing. My pleasure.

Comment: Wait, so is it okay to choose a,b to be any arbitrary constant? I think we can right?

Comment: Yes.  You sort of have two free variables.  You can choose them arbitrarily, and solve for the others.  It's actually a linear system, which you could  solve by row-reduction followed by back substitution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115221/discussion-between-logan-and-chris-custer).